# how to implement looping in infromatica also what its performance

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, etl, informatica

I wonder how to implement a loop on cursor in Informatica 10.4.1 also what will the performance be if it will be very bad with very large data? as I need to migrate an SQL procedure from SQL-server to Informatica to run on apache spark

I found multiple old articles talk about to make parent and child workflows in which the parent called the child with a control table using processed_flag, but I need an easier design with the best practice to get good performance with a large number of rows.

Comment: Are you sure you need a `CURSOR` though? What query do you want to write that you feel can't be expressed in a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Performance will be the poorest using a `CURSOR`, closely followed by a `WHILE`. A rCTE will be more performant, and a non-iterative the fastest. There *are* odd ball cases where a mixture is fastest; but these are (like I said) odd ball cases.

Comment: You can implement `LOOP` using Java Transformation. And performance will depend on data volume and you need to test that out  Also new informatica has a `LOOP` transformation but that need some research.

Comment: Implementing code in Informatica should always be a last resort - there is almost always a solution to any problem that can be implemented just using the available components. Writing code negates many of the benefits of using an ETL tool and if you go down that path you might as well start writing all your ETL in code (Python PL/SQL, etc.). If you start writing code then it becomes a 'black box' to Informatica and you start to lose your lineage/traceability capabilities

Comment: Why not try to focus on >what is there to be done< rather than >how to do a loop< ? Loop is the worst possible way and perhap whatever you got there could be improved?